# Integrating $\int \frac{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus

The integral is: $$\int \frac{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\text{d}x$$
it seems very intimidating, I might need to transform the equation to a simpler form but not sure what exactly it is that will make the integration easier..

Comment: $$\dfrac{d(\sin x+\cos x)}{dx}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Use $u$ substitution.  Let $u=\sin x+\cos x$. Then $du=\cos x-\sin x\,dx$.  So,
$$\int\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx=-\int \frac{du}u.$$